# Half down; half on delivery - How do you invoice that?

Tags: gnucash

I know of a business that charges $100 for a repair.

They charge $50 on acceptance of the job, then $50 on delivery.

One could issue two invoices, tying them together with a job for the customer. Post the first invoice immediately and process the payment. The second invoice remains unposted until the repair is complete. Then post that one and eventually pay it.

Is this the best -- or only -- way to do this, or is there another way?

Seems like a lot of extra steps.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Also, of course there are other ways of doing it. Just the fact you are asking implies that it is not universal. I'm confused what you are trying to figure out.

Comment: Are you asking what they business should do in GnuCash from *their* perspective, or what the customer should do in GnuCash from *their* perspective?

Comment: Asking how the business should handle it in GNC. I'm asking because this is the way I came up with, but there might be better ways to do it I don't know about.

Comment: Please tag replies with e.g. "@JivanPal" at the beginning so that the person is notified, else only the person who posted the question/answer you are commenting on is notified :-) I would personally basically do it the way you have suggested, though I would not create any later invoices (which you suggested to create but leave unposted) until the client owes it, because invoices cannot be deleted in GnuCash. In the event that the job is never completed, you would then have an unposted invoice which you cannot get rid of.

Comment: I would rely on my contract with the client to remind me of the amounts owed after certain stages of the job have been completed, until such time as they have been completed, after which I would create and post an invoice for the relevant amount.